# Remove buffer in catalog_apply()?

Tags: buffer, lidar, lidr, catalog

I am using `catalog_apply()` to normalize las points using `lasnormalize()` and segment individual trees using `lastrees()`. This is modified from the `catalog_apply()` [lidR documentation (p.10)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf):

```r
library(lidR)

my_tree_detection_method <- function(cluster, ws)
{
  las <- readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  las_n = lasnormalize(las, tin())
  ttops <- lastrees(las_n, li2012(R = 3, speed_up = 5))
  # ttops is a SpatialPointsDataFrame that contains the tree tops in our region of interest
  # plus the trees tops in the buffered area. We need to remove the buffer otherwise we will get
  # some trees more than once.
  # bbox <- raster::extent(cluster)
  # ttops <- raster::crop(ttops, bbox)
  return(ttops)
}

ws <- "/path/to/my/las/data"
ctg <- readLAScatalog(ws)
lidR:::catalog_laxindex(ctg) # Build index

opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 10
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 1000

opt <- list(need_buffer = TRUE) # catalog_apply will throw an error if buffer = 0
output <- catalog_apply(ctg, my_tree_detection_method, ws = 5, .options = opt)
```

The example uses the following to remove the processing buffer:

```r
# bbox <- raster::extent(cluster)
# ttops <- raster::crop(ttops, bbox)
```

However, my modified example using `lastrees()` is not a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` and, I believe, cannot utilize `extent()` and `crop()` to remove the processing buffer.

What is the preferred way to remove the buffer used for processing in `catalog_apply()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is covered by [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html). The documentation of `catalog_apply` says:

> ### Buffered data
>
> The LAS objects read by the user function have a special attribute called `buffer` that indicates, for each point, if it comes from a buffered area or not. Points from non-buffered areas have a 'buffer' value of 0, while points from buffered areas have a 'buffer' value of 1, 2, 3 or 4, where 1 is the bottom buffer and 2, 3 and 4 are the left, top and right buffers, respectively. This allows for filtering of buffer points if required.

Consequently you can do

```
ttops <- lasfilter(ttops, buffer == 0)
```

Comment: In my case, would I apply the buffer removal to the `ttops` variable inside the function?: `las_no_buffer <- lasfilter(ttops, buffer == 0)`

Comment: Yes you're right.  Be aware that it creates a copy of the point cloud and thus requires memory. But this is how R works...